# How do I display loading dots in a repeating manner in this PowerShell script to indicate a task is in progress of being completed?

Tags: powershell

I created a simple PowerShell script for testing network devices, below is a shortened version of it:

```
$localhost = "127.0.0.1"
$ipAddresses = @($localhost)

foreach ($ping in $ipAddresses) {
    while ($ping -eq $localhost) {
        Write-Host "Pinging localhost..."
            break
        }
    if (Test-Connection $ping -Count 4) {
        Write-Host "Ping successful`n"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    } else {
        Write-Host "Ping unsuccessful`n"
    }
}

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250

Write-Host "Testing complete"
```

I want to the dots in `Write-Host "Pinging localhost...` to display in a repeating manner one at a time for a maximum of three times until the task is finished.

Like this:   `.` `..` `...`
^^^I want the dots to reset back to 0, hence the blank space

I added a `for` loop and the dots are behaving how I want them to, the only thing is they don't reset to 0 after the 3rd dot appears.

```
foreach ($ping in $ipAddresses) {
    while ($ping -eq $localhost) {
        Write-Host "Pinging localhost" **-NoNewline
        for ($i = 1; $i -le 3; $i++) {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
        Write-Host "." -NoNewline
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
    }**
            break
        }
```

Comment: Your logic is flawed tho if `$ping` is equal `$localhost` that `while` loop breaks instantly else it will never enter that loop. In addition, `Test-Connection` blocks the thread while pinging its not async. As aside, even tho updating a console line is possible, there is a cmdlet already designed for tracking progress (`Write-Progress`).

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Is it possible you for you to further explain how the while loop  breaks instantly...the code runs fine, I'm not understanding.

Comment: Your code enters the `while` loop on `$ping -eq $localhost` displays `"Pinging localhost..."` then that loop instantly breaks and then you enter the `Test-Connection $ping -Count 4` condition. So what's there to wait for? If you want to ping a host there is no `while` loop needed in this case.